# Google Cloud - Access the Source Repositories

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to access the google-cloud source repository using ruby client.The idea is to download the particular file from that source repository.

I tried is to access resource_manage(given below), but I could not find a way to access the source-repository

```
resource_manager = Google::Cloud::Datastore.new({:credentials => "some_credentials"})
```

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud source repository is a fully compatible Git private repository. Once setup you can use any Ruby git client like [ruby-git](https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git) to do operations on it.

Comment: Yes, check the documentation.